# Delete the parent row not the child row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

This is the result of a datatable on a specific screen size. If all the columns are displayed, there is no problem deleting the row using

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

But when screen size became smaller, this will be the result. I cannot use the above code anymore. Now if I hit the button with the class **deleteRow**, I want to delete the **tr** with the class **parent** and its child (though the child row is not inside the parent row), not just the closest row. There could be many rows that have class **parent** so I just want to delete the row associates to the childs' row.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.parent').remove();`

Comment: you haven't provided enough information here.  please add your markup and explain what "the row associates to the childs' row" means.  if child is not inside of the parent, what is the criteria for them being associated?

Comment: please refer to what i have said, datatable

Answer (score 2):

*I want to delete the **tr with the class parent**, not just the closest row.*

Then include that extra info `.parent` in the selector like so:

```
$(this).closest('tr.parent').remove();
```

Comment: the child row is not inside the parent row.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).closest('tr.child')
```

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of why this works and what this code is doing?

Comment: This can only delete the row with child class. I want to delete the child row closest to the button and its parent row

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the samples I've put together here, I've tried to split into many cases that you can reference and re-apply to your project.

Let me know which's suitable for you and I can explain it clearer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete-single-parent').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $this.click(function() {
      // $(this) = the element button clicked
      // Try row 1,3,5
      $(this).closest('tr.parent').remove();
      
      // Try row 2,4,6. Assuming "parent" is always a sibling of current `child`
      $(this).closest('tr.child').prev().remove();
    })
  });
  
  // This queries to the top (table), and find all parent rows to remove
  // Will remove row 1,3,5 only
  $('.delete-all-parents').click(function() {
    $(this)
       .closest('table')
       .find('tr.parent')
       .remove();
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>
      <div>1</div>
      <button class="delete-single-parent">Delete Direct parent</button>
      <button class="delete-all-parents">Delete row 1,3,5</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <div>2</div>
      <button class="delete-single-parent">Delete Parent (row 1)</button>
      <button class="delete-all-parents">Delete row 1,3,5</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>
      <div>3</div>
      <button class="delete-single-parent">Delete Direct parent</button>
      <button class="delete-all-parents">Delete row 1,3,5</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <div>4</div>
      <button class="delete-single-parent">Delete Parent (row 3)</button>
      <button class="delete-all-parents">Delete row 1,3,5</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>
      <div>5</div>
      <button class="delete-single-parent">Delete Direct parent</button>
      <button class="delete-all-parents">Delete row 1,3,5</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <div>6</div>
      <button class="delete-single-parent">Delete Parent (row 5)</button>
      <button class="delete-all-parents">Delete row 1,3,5</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed my own issue. I added attribute to the parent row upon page loading.

```
<tr data_id = {{ $item->id }}>
```

this will make the **tr** unique so that I can call this later to delete the parent as well as the child row.

to delete the child where the button is placed

```
$(this).closest('tr.child').remove();
```

and added code to delete the parent row through attribute as selector.

```
$('[data_id="'+ row_id +'"]').remove();
```

so upon ajax success, I will call these two.

```
$tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
    $(this).closest('tr.child').remove();
    $('[data_id="'+ row_id +'"]').remove(); 
});
```